Bold not working with NewTx package when writing in Japanese
The majority of my document is in Italian but it has some parts in Japanese: installing the NewTx package seems to disable bold Japanese texts. Is there a way to turn off the package locally (for a whole chapter, titles of sections etc. included) or override it with a different font only for Japanese?
Edit: edited the question because italics don't work with Japanese either way
Edit: here is a code example
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX spellcheck = it-IT
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
    
Italian. \textbf{Italian.} \textit{Italian.}\\
日本語 \textbf{日本語} \textit{日本語}

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}

Here how it is compiled:

Here how it is compiled without the NewTx package:


Welcome! An example of code is needed, so we can see what's going wrong.

please provide a complete small document that shows your issue, I wouldn't expect changing the latin script font has any effect on Japanese, does that have italic at all anyway??

Thank you very much for your answers. I added an example code.

Apparently, CJKutf8 doesn't understand the b setting for \bfdefault.
Italic doesn't make sense for Japanese, though, so you'll always get upright shape.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}

\begin{document}

Italian. \textbf{Italian.} \textit{Italian.}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
日本語 \textbf{日本語} \textit{日本語}
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}



Thank you very much for your answer.
